# Minimum of $\frac{1}x + \frac{10}y$, for $x,y>0$ such that $x+y+\sqrt{xy} =3$?

Tags: inequality

In this question, I have tried many different methods and algebraic equations but I can't find a way to get to the answer.

Let $x$ and $y$ be positive real numbers such that $x+y+\sqrt{xy} =3$
Then min value of $\frac{1}x + \frac{10}y$ is ?

Ans is given 49/6

I took $x$ and $y$ to RHS and squared and some algebraic changes to reach
$(x-y)^2 + 3(x-2)(y-2) = 3$

But am stuck at this point.
I thought maybe I could get some help from Engels inequality but that also took me nowhere.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: [Choosing a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) is also an important part of [asking a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/42969)

Comment: At the very least, say which chapter of your lectures is concerned by these exercises. Are you studying conic curves, extremas with Lagrange multipliers, etc. ?

Comment: Yes I am studying conic sections but not so sure about the other 2

Comment: It was given as 1/x + 10/y<= 49/6

Comment: Therefore $49/6$ is the **maximal** value* of the expression in the left hand side.

Comment: @JeanMarie sir will you please elaborate

Comment: Explanation: if, whatever the value of $x$ and $y$, we have $1/x+10/y \le 49/8$ it means that $49/8$ is larger of equal to the maximal  value that $1/x+10/y$ can reach.

Comment: I don't know "Engels inequality" ? Is it Capital :) ?

Comment: According to Engels inequality
$\frac {x1^2}{a1} + \frac {x2^2}{a2} + ........... +\frac {xn^2}{an} ≤ \frac {(x1+ x2+ .......... + xn)^2}{a1+a2+............+an}$

Comment: Thanks. Another reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titu%27s_lemma) under another name...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $k = \sqrt{\frac{y}{x}} > 0$.
We have $y = k^2 x$.
The given condition is written as
$x + k^2 x + kx = 3$ which results in
$$x = \frac{3}{k^2 + k + 1},
\quad y = \frac{3k^2}{k^2 + k + 1}.$$

We need to find the minimum of
$$f(k) := \frac{k^2 + k + 1}{3} + \frac{10(k^2 + k + 1)}{3k^2}.$$

We have
$$f'(k) = \frac{(k - 2)(2k^3 + 5k^2 + 10k + 10)}{3k^3}.$$

Thus, $f(k)$ is strictly decreasing
on $(0, 2)$, and strictly increasing on $(2, \infty)$.
The minimum of $f(k)$ is achieved at $k = 2$.
We have $f(2) = 49/6$.

The minimum is $49/6$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a proof, just a commentary on your attempt and a visual representation.

I am puzzled by this exercise which necessitates indeed to have a certain knowledge of conic curves (you say you have this knowledge) but also of techniques of minimization that look beyond the use of simple differentiation (and you say you don't know the technique of Lagrange multipliers).

Nevertheless, I show you what I have done graphically without saying it is a solution.

[image]

*Fig. 1: Hyperbolas $(C'_m)$ for $m$ ranging from $30/6$ (the highest) to $49/6$, the lowest, which is the solution, just tangent to the arc of ellipse.*

First of all, your transformation by squaring into :

$$(x-y)^2 + 3(x-2)(y-2) = 3$$

brings in a "spurious arc" of curve ; indeed, to the (blue) curve with equation

$$(C) \ : \ \ \ \ x+y+\sqrt{xy}=3,$$

you add the (cyan) curve $x+y-\sqrt{xy}=3$ which is  "parasitic".

How are the red curves defined ? By parametric equations :

$$(C'_m) \ : \ \ \ \ \frac{1}{x}+\frac{10}{y}=m$$

which are branches of hyperbolas.

The question boils down to find the largest value of $m$ for which there is a point $(x,y)$ belonging to $C$ and $C'_m$. Indeed, this looks to happen for $m=49/6$. But a visual conviction is not a proof.

SAGE program which has generated Fig. 1 :

> ```
> var('x y');
> g=implicit_plot(x+y+sqrt(x*y)-3, (x,0,5), (y,0,5),color='blue');
> h=implicit_plot(x+y-sqrt(x*y)-3, (x,0,5), (y,0,5),color='cyan');
> g=g+h;
> for m in range(30,49) :
> h=implicit_plot((10/y+1/x-m/6),(x,0,5),(y,0,5),color='red');
> g=g+h;
> show(g);
> ```